# jqplot on bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jqplot, bootstrap-tabs

im having problems to draw a simple jqplot graph on a bootstrap tab.

HTML:

```
<div id="tab">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li id="tabvariables" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" class="custom_tab" href="#variables">Variables</a></li>
<li id="tabphoto"><a data-toggle="tab" class="custom_tab" href="#photo">photo</a></li>
<li id="tabtendencia"><a data-toggle="tab" class="custom_tab" href="#tendencia">Tendencia</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="variables" class="tab-pane fade in active custom_variables"></div>
<div id="photo" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
<div id="tendencia" class="tab-pane fade">
<div id="contenedorGrafica" style="border: 1px solid RED;">
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (example from jqplot web):

```
var l1 = [18, 36, 14, 11];
var l2 = [[2, 14], [7, 2], [8,5]];
var l3 = [4, 7, 9, 2, 11, 5, 9, 13, 8, 7];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [l1, l2, l3],  {
    title: "I was hidden",
    lengend:{show:true},
    series:[{},{yaxis:'y2axis'}, {yaxis:'y3axis'}],
    cursor:{show:true, zoom:true},
    axesDefaults:{useSeriesColor:true, rendererOptions: { alignTicks: true}}
});

$('#tab').tabs({ activate : function(event, ui) {
    plot1.replot();
}});
```

when i click on the graph tab (tabtendencia) it doesnt draw anything but i can see that it reserves a space to try draw the graph.

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewRhp.png

Answer (score -1):

with

```
$('#tab').tabs({ activate : function(event, ui) {
    plot1.replot();
}});
```

or

```
$("#tabtendencia").click(function() {
    plot1.replot();
});
```

goes right but if i do double click on the tab...

i dont understand...

Comment: thanks, finally i created a function into "tab" creation to create a jqplot and it goes right